# How do I set the activecell on a worksheet to be the property of a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, select, selection

I'm trying to set the active cell equal to a value, but not override or set that value. I just want it to take the "Name" from Combobox1 and set that cell as the active one. But this code keeps overriding values.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PR Calendar").Activate

Set ActiveCell.Select = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1,Range("EventPage"), 1, False)

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: not sure if all the terms Value mean the same cell or what you mean by "it" or "that cell" *possibly that cell being active cell?) the code is overriding the value in the active cell? a different cell? or the combo box value?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR Calendar").Activate
    Sheets("PR Calendar").Range("PRcol1").Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.ComboBox1, Range("PRcol1"), False)).Select

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: That's what I had, it keeps setting the value of the active cell equal to the lookup value instead of selecting it. Thanks though.

Comment: @iontom What does `Application.VLookup(Sheets("PR Calendar").ComboBox1, Range("EventPage"), 1, False)` return ? Fyi its there in your active cell.

Comment: Figured it out! Had to use .Find



    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim result As Variant
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PR Calendar").Activate
    result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1, Range("PRcol1"), 1, False)
    Set rRng = Range("PRcol1").Find(result)
    Application.Goto rRng, Scroll:=True
    Unload Me
    End Sub